# How to form an object from a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to form my data to a specific formate. I have normal data coming from a query like this

```
[
 {
   category: "Business"
 },
 {
   category: "Events"
 },
 {
  category: "Vip Meetup"
 }
]
```

I want to form above data using a foreach loop to bellow structure

```
    [
        'Business'  => __( 'Business', 'plugin-domain' ),
        'Events' => __( 'Events', 'plugin-domain' ),
        'Vip Meetup' => __( 'Vip Meetup', 'plugin-domain' ),
    ];
```

How can I create a data structure like this?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: HAve you tried anything? Decoding data? Writing a `foreach`?

Comment: Yes, I have been trying with foreach, I get the data. trying like this 

```$options = []; 
  foreach($eventCats as $cat){
   
   array_push($options, "$cat->category =>  _( $cat->category, 'plugin-domain')");
  }
  echo json_encode($options);```

But it doesn't form the object as expected

Comment: [edit] your question, do not paste code in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this should be somehting like:

```
$options = []; 
foreach ($eventCats as $cat) {
    // Add an element to array under key `$cat->category`
    // Value of the element will be result of calling `__` function
    $options[$cat->category] = __( $cat->category, 'plugin-domain');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works, could you explain a bit how it works? Thanks again

Comment: Not really sure what to explain, but added some comments.